# How to initialise 2d ArrayList with streams

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have **2D ArrayList** like this one: `ArrayList<ArrayList<SingleCell>> grid;`.
I want to initialize it like in this example with normal ArrayList:

```
List<Person> persons = Stream.generate(Person::new)
                             .limit(60)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I’m getting width and height when constructing the holder class. I want to fill the 2D ArrayList with `new SingleCell();` based on the passed size. 
Is it possible to do it like this and if it is possible how can i do it ? Also is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, `Person::new` is used to generate the elements of a list, but this generator could be any lambda you like, so how about something like this:

```
List<List<SingleCell>> grid =
    Stream.generate(()->
        Stream.generate(SingleCell::new)
        .limit(width)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
    .limit(height)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```